# Click , Select and Clone to another field

Tags: html, css, select, click, clone

I would like to create a scene which would help me to copy some items by click and select option.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsZLP/7/), if you go ahead and have a look on the scene. you'll see 1 Red, 1 Blue and 1 Green boxes.

```
#container {
    width:500px;
    height:600px;
    display:block;
}
#red {
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
#blue {
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
}
#green {
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
    background-color:green;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="blue"></div>
    <div id="green"></div>
</div>
```

My purpose is selecting one of the small boxes either blue or red by clicking "ONCE" and when I click anywhere inside the Green box I would like to clone inside. For instance, If I click to Red, it must be selected and when I click inside the Green box I must clone it as many times as I click inside the box.

Which way I should follow to do this and what kind of captions I should start searching for the method?

I found this following link but it wasn't very much helpful to get the idea; http://simonsarris.com/blog/140-canvas-moving-selectable-shapes

Thank you very much for your help from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured a way to handle this case.  Without **`Javascript`** you can't do handle it.  Whereas here I have used **`jQuery`** and here is my logic:

1) I have created a *global variable* **`isRedOrBlue`** to identify what element user have selected.  Whenever I click the *red* or *blue* `div`, I will be changing it accordingly.

```
var isRedOrBlue;
$('#red').on('click', function () {
    isRedOrBlue = "red";
    // For identification, I'm adding border
    $(this).css({
        "border": "1px solid #ccc"
    });
    //Vice versa I'm removing for other
    $('#blue').css({
        "border": ""
    })
});
$('#blue').on('click', function () {
    isRedOrBlue = "blue";
    // For identification, I'm adding border
    $(this).css({
        "border": "1px solid #ccc"
    })
    //Vice versa I'm removing for other
    $('#red').css({
        "border": ""
    })
});
```

2) Now when I click the `green` `div`, based on **`isRedOrBlue`** variable *I will be **[cloning](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)** it and **[appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)** it to the green `div`.*

```
$('#green').on('click', function () {
    if (isRedOrBlue) { // When none selected
        console.log(isRedOrBlue)
        $('#' + isRedOrBlue).clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

### [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/XtSLJ/)

Hope you can understand my logic that I've used above.